# How to write a SQL Statement in Oracle SQL with two AND conditions applying on same column within same table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help to write a Oracle SQL query, details are below:

I have a table `offender_gang_affiliations` with two different columns named `offender_id` and `dept_dvsn_code`.

I want a list of all offender id's for which there are rows in the table with a `dept_dvsn_code` of 'A' as well as `dept_dvsn_code` of 'J'. I've tried applying various `AND` and `OR` conditions but I haven't been able to come up with anything that worked.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want something like

```
SELECT offender_id
  FROM offender_gang_affiliations
 WHERE dept_dvsn_code IN ('A','J')
 GROUP BY offender_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dept_dvsn_code) = 2
```

Another way of formulating the query would be

```
SELECT offender_id
  FROM offender_gang_affiliations
 WHERE dept_dvsn_code = 'A'
INTERSECT
SELECT offender_id
  FROM offender_gang_affiliations
 WHERE dept_dvsn_code = 'J'
```

Generally, I would expect the first option to be more efficient.  Depending on the developer, the second option may end up being clearer.